# jQuery function not called at page load in Angular 2

Tags: javascript, jquery, angular

I am trying to call jQuery function (i.e. initialize bootstrap selectpicker) at page load in ng2 app:

```
jQuery(this.elementRef.nativeElement).find("select").selectpicker({
  iconBase: 'fa',
  tickIcon: 'fa-check',
  title: '...'
});
```

(assume that jQuery and elementRef are defined and it works well in other cases)

I try to call this function in ngOnInit, ngAfterContentInit, ngAfterViewInit but with no luck.

I suspect it calls before element is rendered or so.

Here is my template of select which I try to convert into bootstrap selectpicker:

```
<select ngControl="hashtags" [(ngModel)]="hashtags" multiple>
  <option *ngFor="#hashtag of card.hashtags" [value]="hashtag.id" (click)="selectHashtag(hashtag.id)">{{hashtag.name}}</option>
</select>
```

Any ideas how to call it right?

**UPD:** seems like the issue comes from a fact that a form (and my select element) is rendered inside ngIf:

```
<div *ngIf="card">
...
</div>
```

so, at the moment of rendering page and calling ngOnInit() form is not rendered yet.
I will try to work it around by applying different approach, but how would you call function AFTER http request and form render are complete?

Comment: If you put this in ngOnInit and put a breakpoint on the line, does `jQuery(this.elementRef.nativeElement).find("select")` return anything?

Comment: no, it doesn't: `jQuery []`   however, if I call `$("select")` after page load it returns `jQuery [<select class="ng-untouched ng-pristine ng-invalid">]`

Comment: Ok. What does jQuery(this.elementRef.nativeElement).find("select") return if you run it later?

Comment: it returns `jQuery [<select class="ng-untouched ng-pristine ng-invalid">]` if I bind `console.log(jQuery(this.elementRef.nativeElement).find("select"));` to a button and call it later. Is it what you asked for?

Comment: please see UPD in the question body with more details...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

and the right answer is to call it inside `ngAfterViewChecked() {}`

AfterViewChecked callback triggers everytime page is changed, thus to make sure my functions are called only once I set flags i.e. `selectpickerEnabled = true` and check them before calling function again.

I believe there must be the right way to do it, but that's how I am going to solve it for now...

Answer (score 2):

Wouldn't it be similar to this:

```
import {Component, ElementRef, OnInit} from 'angular2/core';
declare var jQuery:any;

@Component({
    selector: 'jquery-integration',
    templateUrl: './components/jquery-integration/jquery-integration.html'
})
export class JqueryIntegration implements OnInit {
    elementRef: ElementRef;
    constructor(elementRef: ElementRef) {
        this.elementRef = elementRef;
    }
    ngOnInit() {
        jQuery(this.elementRef.nativeElement).draggable({containment:'#draggable-parent'});
    }
}
```

More info here: http://www.syntaxsuccess.com/viewarticle/using-jquery-with-angular-2.0

Comment: correct, that's exactly how I do it, using sample from Torgeir Helgevold, and it does not work for me.

Comment: How is the select tag included in the template?

Comment: `<select ngControl="hashtags" [(ngModel)]="hashtags" multiple>
        <option *ngFor="#hashtag of card.hashtags" [value]="hashtag.id" (click)="selectHashtag(hashtag.id)">{{hashtag.name}}</option>
      </select>`

Comment: I have not used selectPicker, but here is a plunker with a bootstrap dropdown. Maybe you can use that as a baseline: http://plnkr.co/edit/up5UdH?p=preview